# How can I add error bars to a Google Data Studio chart?

Tags: looker-studio

I can see there are STDDEV functions for calculated fields, but I cannot find any place in the documentation a way suggesting to either add or enable error bars on charts. Is this not supported?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible but may be possible in future when the community visualisations are made generally available

[community visualisations](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/)

Answer (score 0):

I got a rough approximation of this by charting my column a number of times on the same chart, using a different aggregate each time (e.g. avg, stddev, min, max).

I'd love to see actual error bars, or even quartile aggregation, to make this nicer.